# Making an image control invert its colors depending on theme

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to work out how to have an `Image` control in my Windows Phone application invert its colors based on the global background setting (either "Dark" or "Light") chosen by the user in Settings->Themes->Background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in way to invert image colors within the framework.

Instead, because of the overhead of doing this on the phone, you should create both versions of the image at design/build time and then choose which version to display from your code by detecting [Theme Visibility and Opacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

Comment: Nowadays, ApplicationBar for Windows Phone do this invert of colors on png images. I would like to know how too.

`code
<shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="AppBarSimple" IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
   <shell:ApplicationBar IconButton  x:Name="btnList" Click="btnList_Click" IconUri="/Images/feature.search.png" Text="consultar"/>
</shell:ApplicationBar>
`

Answer (score 4):

I must add that what i did in the end was a continuation of what Matt wrote.

- create two different images that have different versions of the image (dark and light) and place them in the exact same position
- set their visibility based on the theme resource

the code looks like this:

```
<Image Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,220" Name="imgDark" Stretch="Fill" Visibility="{StaticResource PhoneLightThemeVisibility}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="30" Source="/MyApplication;component/imageDarkTheme.png" />
<Image Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,220" Name="imgLoading" Stretch="Fill" Visibility="{StaticResource PhoneDarkThemeVisibility}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="30" Source="/MyApplication;component/imageLightTheme.png" />
```

Answer (score 4):

This Question is 1.5 years old now. But [here](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Converters&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#themedImageConverter) is the easiest way to do what you want. The example given there is very simple like

```
<Button>
    <Image Stretch="None" Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ThemedImageConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource PhoneBackgroundColor} }"
           DataContext="/WP7SampleProject4;component/Images/{0}/appbar.feature.camera.rest.png" />
</Button>
```