# How to swap images based on the current theme WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, themes

I've failed certification because I have an image that's all white. So when a user switches to the light theme it fails because you can't see it.  How do I swap this imaged based on the theme applied?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13977950/2387977

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In XAML

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
```

In the view model that contains property `ImageSource`

```
public string ImageSource
{
  get
  {
    if( (Visibility)App.Current.Resources["PhoneDarkThemeVisibility"] 
      == Visibility.Visible ) {
        return "/path/to/dark/image.png";

    } else {
        return "/path/to/light/image.png";

    }
  }
  private set {}
}
```

This may not change the picture if the user tombstones your app, changes the theme and switches back to the app.

One way to handle that scenario is to cache the current theme setting in the App class constructor, then compare it with the current setting within `App.Application_Activated`, if they're different you'll need to somehow indicate that the above view model needs to fire a property changed notification for `ImageSource`.

Comment: if I wanted to call a property directly (not using a view model currently) how could I call into the xaml.cs for this getter?

Comment: @Toran Billups: Assign an `x:Name` to the `Image` in XAML. Then you can use that name in code behind to assign the image source as follows: `ImageName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/path/to/dark/image.png", UriKind.Relative));`

Comment: interesting - this doesn't appear to be cs friendly as is? any help with this markup (can't seem to grab it by name) <Button><Button.Background><ImageBrush x:Name ....

Comment: @Toran Billups Your last post got cutoff. But if you're assigning an `ImageBrush` in code behind you need to create an `ImageBrush` from the `BitmapImage`. `new ImageBrush() { ImageSource = new BitmapImage( new Uri( ... )) };`

Comment: I actually prefer to have the ImageSource (in XAML - not cs) fire off to a static obj for this url - but x:Static doesn't seem to be valid within ImageBrush- any idea if this is possible?

Comment: @Toran Billups Unfortunately, Silverlight does not support the `x:Static` markup. If you google it you'll find workarounds like [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yl/archive/2009/07/22/x-type-and-x-static-in-silverlight.aspx) one

Answer (score 17):

Question [Making an image control invert its colors depending on theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656880/making-an-image-control-invert-its-colors-depending-on-theme) has a simple XAML only answer:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Center"Stretch="None" Visibility="{StaticResource PhoneLightThemeVisibility}" Source="/MyApplication;component/imageDarkTheme.png" />
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None" Visibility="{StaticResource PhoneDarkThemeVisibility}"Source="/MyApplication;component/imageLightTheme.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone following my comments above - I had to switch from ImageBrush to Image directly (xaml below)

```
<Button Tag="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="-10,20,0,0" BorderThickness="0" Width="105" Height="102" Click="ShowKioskOnMap_Click">
                                    <Image Source="../images/arrow.png" Width="55" Height="53" ImageOpened="Image_ImageOpened"/>
                                </Button>
```

Next in the consructor of the page I'm using --I did the theme lookup to prevent any issues when the app state is restored from taking a phone call for instance (or just loading up the view for the first time)

```
        InitializeComponent();

        theme = ""; //field level var (could make it dark by default if needed)
        if ((Visibility)App.Current.Resources["PhoneDarkThemeVisibility"] == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            theme = "dark";
        }
        else
        {
            theme = "light";
        }
```

And I had to implement the following in my open event to switch based on theme

```
    private void Image_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var brush = (sender as Image);
        if (brush.Stretch == Stretch.Uniform)
        {
            if (theme == "light")
                brush.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../images/arrowLight.png", UriKind.Relative));

            brush.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
        }
    }
```